# How to execute two queries one after another in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm new to JDBC.
I want to add new record to the table if the condition(the model in my example is not present) is not true. But the compiler show me ***" Can not issue executeUpdate() or executeLargeUpdate() for SELECTs "*** when I tried to execute two queries. What else can I do to insert a new record if the condition is not true?

```java
public class AskUser5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Manufacturer:");
        String Manufacturer = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Model:");
        String model = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Speed:");
        int speed = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ram:");
        int ram = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("HD Size:");
        int hd_size = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Price:");
        int price = sc.nextInt();
        Connection con = Getconnection.getconnection();
        String query  = "select * from pc";
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                if(model.equals(rs.getString("model"))) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Model Aviable");
                    flag=true;
                }
                
            }
            
            if(flag == false) {
                System.out.println("There's no such model here");
                PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into pc (model,speed,ram,hd,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                 ps2.setString(1, model);
                 ps2.setInt(2, speed);
                 ps2.setInt(3, ram);
                 ps2.setInt(4, hd_size);
                 ps2.setInt(5, price);
                 ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error due to " + e.getMessage());
        }
    

    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your attempt with two queries. Tell us the error. We can't tell you what you did wrong when you don't show us anything.

Comment: Ditto. I copied your code locally and the compiler is fine with it (it compiles without errors). What errors do you see? Are they compilation errors, or runtime errors?

Comment: Also, I don't follow that you "tried to execute two queries" but the code you posted shows only one query (?) – `select * from pc`

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've update my problem to be more specific

Comment: @Bohemian I'm using Mysql

Comment: Maybe you deliberately want to do things this way: 1st SQL selects everything; you scan it all for the one record; you perform an insert if needed. You could, instead, probably do all of that in one SQL statement (e.g. `insert ... where not exists ...`). At the very least, instead of `select *` you could use a prepared statement to select the record for the specific input value, or `select count...` of the matching record(s) to know if it exists or not (no need to scan the whole table).

Comment: ps.executeUpdate(); should be  ps2.executeUpdate();

Comment: @ChengThao Big thanks. I didn't see it. lol

Comment: Thank you all for sparing your time helping me out.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one statement:

```
INSERT into pc (model,speed,ram,hd,price)
SELECT ?,?,?,?,?
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM model WHERE mode_id = ?)
```